# How to get start and end date where today's current time is in?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have only one column called "date". And in that column I have the following data:

```
2022-01-07
2022-01-22
2022-02-08
2022-02-20 
2022-03-02
2022-03-15
2022-03-25
2022-04-04
2022-04-20 select date
2022-05-05 select date
2022-05-17
2022-05-29
2022-06-15
2022-06-24
2022-07-04
2022-07-13
2022-07-22
2022-07-31
2022-08-10
2022-08-27
2022-09-12
2022-09-28
2022-10-10
2022-10-26
2022-11-10
2022-11-25
2022-12-07
2022-12-20
2022-12-30
2023-01-14
2023-01-28
2023-02-11
2023-02-22
2023-03-06
2023-03-15
2023-03-24
2023-04-05
2023-04-17
2023-04-29
2023-05-08
```

I needed to know which moment of this date I am. For example, if today is day **2022-04-24** then i need to select before and after date.

I need to select the two dates according to the current time where I am.

How can I do this in MySQL?

Comment: What do you mean by `I needed to know which moment of this date I am`? Can you give another example?

Comment: I think you need the most restrictive two dates having the date you put in the query?

Comment: Edge cases: 1. What if the input date is there in the table?

Comment: @Saif I have several dates in the database, I needed to select the previous and next time closest to the date I'm on

Comment: 2. What if there are no such rows to select? I mean no end date or no start date.

Comment: I got confused because the image you shared had other dates highlighted.

Comment: I took the picture, realized it wouldn't help much

Comment: It's just as well the [image](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527) was removed, as they shouldn't be used for textual data.

Comment: Since SQL includes data definition, a [mcve] for an [SQL question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/90527) should include [DDL](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statements for sample tables and [DML](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) statements for sample data (rather than a dump or ad hoc format). Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves.

Comment: Saif's edge cases are still not sufficiently explained. What should the result be for '2022-04-20'? '2000-01-01'? '2199-12-31'?

Comment: Additionally, all clarifications should be [edit]ed into to the question (as explained in the [site guidelines](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [sample code guidelines](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), not left as [comments](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) or [linked](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/90527). For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments. For another, SO is a Q&A site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[MySQL get the nearest future date to given date, from the dates located in different table having Common ID](//stackoverflow.com/q/35230613/90527)", "[Multiple SQL SELECT](//stackoverflow.com/q/7086721/90527)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this via two scalar limit subqueries:

```sql
SELECT
    (SELECT date FROM yourTable WHERE date <= CURDATE() ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1) AS start,
    (SELECT date FROM yourTable WHERE date >= CURDATE() ORDER BY date LIMIT 1) AS end;
```